# Include desired input for a test in defects4j

Tags: testing, random-testing

I want to write a script on top of [defects4j](https://github.com/rjust/defects4j) and try to include my own input for a specific (faulty) test. At the moment I checkout to the specific buggy branch and I just run:

`defects4j compile` and
`defects4j test`
and it runs the test and shows me how many functions are being failed (and show me which function on the "failig_tests" file). However, I want to include my own desired input for that test to see whether the test fails on any input or just some specific ones, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm in the beginning stages.